# C# Selenium fileupload with Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium

My codes are as follows. This is working very good on Google Chrome. Also i can change the download folder. But not good working on Firefox. When I have started test with firefox, it's opening selection window. File is adding to fileupload object but not closing window. Also I have tried some firefox options but not working. If it's not to be, i thinking do make some methods in web application for this. For example, fileupload and filedownload such as.

```js
var fileUpload = td.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='fileInput']"));
fileUpload.SendKeys(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Deneme.txt");


CreateDocument.RunTest(new TestData() {
 Driver = new ChromeDriver(Utils.GetFirefoxOptions("FileUpload")),
  TestPageUrl = theTestPageURL,
  UserName = "deneme",
  Password = "123",
  TestCode = "Deneme",
  TestName = File Upload Testi ",
 Version = "1.0.0.6",
});



public static FirefoxOptions GetFirefoxOptions(string TestCode) {
  CreateDownloadFolder(TestCode);
  FirefoxOptions pf = new FirefoxOptions();
  pf.SetPreference("browser.preferences.instantApply", true);
  pf.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml");
  pf.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
  pf.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", @ "C:\TestDownloads\" + TestCode);
  pf.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 0); pf.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
  return pf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that we use:

It involves using Javascript and a 3rd Party javascript library called Dojo.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor exec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
string content = ... //  <-- This needs to be the string content of the Dojo js library.
content = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
exec.ExecuteScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script');s.innerHTML=atob('" + content + "');window.document.head.appendChild(s);");

var target = ...   // <--  This is the IWebElement that maps to the file upload input dom object.

string targetId = target.GetAttribute("id");
// Add an id if the target doesn't have one
            if (targetId == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetId))
            {
                targetId = "seleniumDragAndDropInput_target";
                exec.ExecuteScript("sId=function(e, i){e.id = i;};sId(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", target.InnerObject, targetId);
            }


exec.ExecuteScript(
                    "var f=dojo.create('form', {id: 'seleniumDragAndDropInput_form', style: {position: 'fixed', left: 0, top: 0, width:'100px', height: '100px'}}, dojo.body());"
                    + "dojo.create('input', { type: 'file', id: 'seleniumDragAndDropInput' }, f);");
            var input = new Textbox(By.Id("seleniumDragAndDropInput"));
            input.TypeText(filePath);  // < -- This is the path to your file on the system

            exec.ExecuteScript(
                    "var files=dojo.byId(\"seleniumDragAndDropInput\").files;"
                    + "var eve=document.createEvent(\"HTMLEvents\");"
                    + "eve.initEvent(\"drop\", true, true);"
                    + "eve.dataTransfer = {files:files};"
                    + "eve.type = \"drop\";document.getElementById('" + targetId + "').dispatchEvent(eve);");

            exec.ExecuteScript("dojo.destroy('seleniumDragAndDropInput_form');");
            if (targetId == "seleniumDragAndDropInput_target")
            {
                exec.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('seleniumDragAndDropInput_target').id = null");
            }
```

We convert the Dojo content to base64 and then decypher it via Javascript atob - this is to get around string escaping issues etc.

This code works on Internet Explorer, FireFox and Chrome.
Essentially - FileUpload inputs are protected from Javascript interactions in order to keep your local files safe from unscrupulous websites.
If you try to interact with a file input in a website with Javascript, it will simply give you an error message.
However, there is a nifty work-around.

You can create your own file input control (using dojo), with a writable path field.
You can then trigger the 'drop' event on the control, but route the 'drop' event to the real file input you want to interact with.

The result is that the file upload is triggered, emulating someone dragging and dropping the file onto the file-upload itself.

This approach is better than most that would try to use Robot etc to interact with File browse dialogs - which can be different depending on your OS and Browser.
In my testing - it at least works for IE, FireFox and Chrome.

The only thing I would warn you is that this will NOT work with Selenium Grid.
As the C# code will not necessarily be running on the same machine as the browser - in which case it will have difficulty resolving the file paths to the file you wish to upload - unless its on a network share that both can access via the same path.